# Trying to prove that the Eigenvalues here are positive

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, change-of-basis

I'm giving a gram matrix $G$ where the first row of G is defined like this $ <v_1,v_1>,<v_1,v_2>...,<v_1,v_n>$and the second row is $<v_1,v_2>,<v_2,v_2>...<v_2,v_n> $ and so on ,with an inner product basis $B=\{v_1...v_n\}$ and also $<v,u>=[v]_B^TG[u]_B$ .I'm supposed to use this given to show that the Egienvalue of G must be positive ,so i thought ill do this $<x,x>=[x]_B^TG[x]_B=[x]_B^T\lambda x=\lambda||x||^2 \implies \lambda>0$,when $x$ is an Egienvector.
But i'm not sure of this solution because of the change of coordinates with respect to the basis B.

Comment: Gram matrices are positive semi definite. So if you know it's a gram matrix, the job is done.

Comment: Yes but I still can't write a solid answer to show this

Comment: Do you think my solution is write ?

Comment: Gram matrices are of the form $X^\top X$ where $X$ is any matrix. That should help you.

Comment: Does this help me correct my way or is this a whole different way of proving ,i'd rather if you help me with what i've started please

Comment: Well. Consider an indefinite matrix B. You still have $x^tBx=x^t\lambda x=\lambda \|x\|^2$ regardless of the sign of $\lambda$. Basically the last implication of your proposal is incorrect unless you know that $G$ is psd. But that's what you're trying to prove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that for any vector $v$, we have
$$
\langle v,v \rangle = [v]_B^T G [v]_B
$$
Now, suppose that $x$ is an eigenvector of $G$ with $\|x\| = 1$.  There exists a $v$ such that $x = [v]_B$ (in particular, take $v = \sum_i x_i v_i$).  We note that
$$
\lambda = \lambda \|x\|^2 = x^T(\lambda x) = [v]_B^T G[v]_B = \langle v,v \rangle > 0
$$
So, all eigenvalues must be positive.

Comment: Congratulations on your reaching 100K!!

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks, not too far off yourself.